# Issues with Manipulate and dynamic variables in plotting

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic, scoping

I'm trying to make a manipulate that shows a parametric plot of a cycloid with manipulators that affect the shape of the curve. My problem seems to be my scoping of the variable `R` in the code below. This is what I've tried so far:

```
x[th_]:=R(th - Sin[th])
y[th_]:=R(1 - Cos[th])

DynamicModule[{R,q=({x[#],-y[#]})&}, Manipulate[
    ParametricPlot[q[ph],{ph,0,th}],
{{th,0,"\[Theta]"},0,2 Pi, Appearance->"Labeled"},
{{R,1,"radius"},0.01,10, Appearance->"Labeled"}]]
```

This results in the dynamic value of `R` not being scoped into `q`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Linked topic should address all your concerns, let me know if you disagree with closing.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
x[R_, th_] := R (th - Sin[th]);
y[R_, th_] := R (1 - Cos[th]);
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{x[R, ph], -y[R, ph]}, {ph, 0, th}], 
   {{th, 0.1,"\[Theta]"}, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
   {{R, 1, "radius"}, 0.01, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but I'd prefer to have R be a constant (in math speak) rather than a parameter. Any way that I can use Dynamic to do this?

Comment: @terry, let's just say it's poor *Mathematica* practice to construct functions that do not take all needed parameters as arguments. So: `R = 2; x[th_] := R (th - Sin[th])` and `x[R_, th_] := R (th - Sin[th])` are OK, but plain `x[th_] := R (th - Sin[th])` and leaving `R` undefined is not.